# Django - Different user types in a DetailView

Tags: django

I have two user types: Buyer and Merchant and I want to display in a page details of the selected user but a detail view can only use one model

**My models**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_buyer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_merchant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_moderator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pgp = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


class Merchant(models.Model):  # items
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'


class Buyer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

**My views**

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
```

**My template and url**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <article>
        <div>
            <p>{{ object.pgp }}</p>
        </div>
    </article>

{% endblock %}


path('profile/<str:username>', usersViews.ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='user-profile'),
```

The only thing that seems to work on the template is object.username, if I try using other names it wont show.
What should I do? Create another model Profile? Change my current view or model?

Edit: I created a Profile Model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buyer = models.OneToOneField(Buyer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    merchant = models.OneToOneField(Merchant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

but then on the view the 2 slug variables

```
slug_field = 'User.username' 
slug_url_kwarg = 'User.username'
```

raised the error of Generic detail view must be called with either an object pk or a slug

Answer (score 0):

Because there's a one-to-one relationship between the User and Merchant and Buyer, you can access both in your template:

```
{{ obj.merchant }}
# or
{{ obj.buyer }}
```

You can then access the properties of Merchant/Buyer:

```
{{ obj.merchant.some_property }}
```